# Check whether text contains x numbers in a row

Tags: python, regex, parsing

Is there an option to check whether the given text contains x numbers in a row?

Example:

```
da$ c0220 -> True
dsad458d69 -> False
```

I think I should use `regular expressions` but I can't figure out how.

Comment: exactly x numbers, or a minimum of x numbers?

Comment: `\d{n}` where `n` is the exact amount, `\d{n,m}` where `n` is the min, `m` is max allowed.

Comment: ...And `\d{n,}` for *at least* n digits

Comment: I think this question is not so unclear that is has to be closed. It is pretty easy to give a regex for both possible cases. Voting to reopen.

Comment: @hwnd `\d{3}` will match `123` in `1234`.

Comment: Of course it will ...OP was not specific, just a general approach so OP gets the idea.

Comment: @hwnd Oh, alright. I have an answer ready just in case this gets reopened.

Comment: Are you looking for strings that contain one or more  *repeating* digit sequences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex below checks for 10 consecutive numbers

```
\d{10}
```

In Python this becomes

```
if re.search(r"\d{10}", subject):
    # Successful match
else:
    # Match attempt failed
```