# Check whether number contains exactly x equal numbers in a row

Tags: python, filter, built-in

I'm looking for a way to check, whether the `string` contains exact x equal numbers in a row (not more). So for example for 3 numbers:  788895 would be `True` but for 7888895 it would be `False`.

I have a list of numbers and I'm going to use a filter on this list.

In case I wanted to filter those numbers, which contains at least 3 numbers in a row, it would be:

```
num = filter(lambda x: any(y in x for y in ['000','111','222'..etc]),numbers)
```

But how to change this filter to return `44000125` but not `44000012` because there is 4 zeros in a row?

EDIT: I can do brute force approach to test each number, if there is no any `['0000','1111'...]` but I think there should be the better way.

Comment: You _could_ have clarified [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34513582/check-whether-text-contains-x-numbers-in-a-row) on this topic...

Comment: How about `1112222`? It contains three ones, but four twos.

Comment: @eumiro Thanks for question, it should be False.

Answer (score 2):

This checks whether the longest chain of identical numbers has the length of exactly three.

```
import itertools as it

max(len(list(v)) for k,v in it.groupby(s) if k.isdigit()) == 3
```

Examples:

```
123       False
1223      False
12223     True
122223    False
1112222   False
aaa1      False
aa111aaaa True
```